# Configure Spotlight to open new window by default

Tags: macos, window, spotlight

I am pretty new to macOS (10.14.5), and I wondered if it was possible to have Spotlight open a new window by default ?

Usually, my workflow is that when I go to a new desktop, I want to open a new window for a software that might already be open on another desktop. I thought Spotlight might help me do it faster than by using the mouse's right click on the dock icon, but it only shifts me back to the desktop where the program is already opened.

Also, I use a tiling window manager called chunkwm, which always forces focus on the app under the mouse. I like it that way, but it prevents me from having the focus on an app that's not on screen and using `cmd-n` to pop a new window.

Thanks

Comment: I think you're going to be fighting two paradigms here - one, that any call to 'activate' will by default bring to the front any app already open rather than call a new instance. The other is that Spaces really really doesn't like apps to be spread to more than a single Space.

Comment: After some tinkering with chunkwm and stuff, I encountered a workaround. The main problem was that I couldn't focus an app on a desktop that didn't have that app opened yet to use the 'Open a new window' shortcut. The desktop switching behavior can be disabled in System Preferences > Mission Control > When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application